# Encrypting the password value used to send an email via a bat file?

Tags: windows, email, batch, batch-file, gmail

I want to send a file to my Gmail account via a bat file and encrypt my email info in that bat file so that if someone opens the bat file they cannot get the email information from it.

### My Script

I'm using this dynamic script Batch Script per help I received from the "[Send a file to an email address using a bat file without exposing the email info?](https://superuser.com/questions/1366274/send-a-file-to-an-email-address-using-a-bat-file-without-exposing-the-email-info)" post. At the moment this script works fine however I have to hard code sensivite values into it which is what I do not avoid if possible.

```
@ECHO OFF

SET GmailAccount=<GmailAccountName>
SET GmailPassword=<GmailPassword>
SET Attachment=<FullAttachmentPath>

CALL :PowerShell
CD /D "%PowerShellDir%"
Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PSScript%' '%GmailAccount%' '%GmailPassword%' '%Attachment%'"
IF EXIST "%~FN0" DEL /Q /F "%~FN0"
EXIT

:PowerShell
SET PowerShellDir=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
SET PSScript=%temp%\~tmpSendeMail.ps1
IF EXIST "%PSScript%" DEL /Q /F "%PSScript%"

ECHO $Username      = $args[0]>> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $EmailPassword = $args[1]>> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $Attachment    = $args[2]>> "%PSScript%"
ECHO                          >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $Username    = $Username                 >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $EmailTo     = "EmailAddress@domain.com" >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $EmailFrom   = "noreply@Whatever.notify" >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $Subject     = "Email Subject"           >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $Body        = "Email Body"              >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $SMTPServer  = "smtp.gmail.com"          >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body) >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $Attachment  = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($Attachment)                            >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $SMTPMessage.Attachments.Add($Attachment)                                                    >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)                               >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true                                                                >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $EmailPassword) >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)                                                               >> "%PSScript%"
GOTO :EOF
```

I'd like to be able to use encrypted values rather than the actual values for certain variables and such so when this script is run if someone sees it, they cannot easily see those sensitive values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Obfuscate Sensitive Strings with PowerShell to Send an Email via a Batch Script

You can use a strategic variation of the PowerShell code mentioned in the ["Simple Obfuscation with PowerShell using Base64 Encoding"](https://mikefrobbins.com/2017/06/15/simple-obfuscation-with-powershell-using-base64-encoding/) post to...

1. Encode the sensitive string(s) you wish to obfuscate to make those not so easily decipherable to anyone without a lot of technical know-how which could potentially see or copy the script logic at runtime
2. Setup the process to cleanup and remove the batch script, and the dynamically generated PowerShell script, after both are executed and run the necessary logic

### Get Encoded String Values

Whatever value you want to obfuscate, you will put that value enclosed within double quotes in the `$SensitiveString` per the below logic and then execute `$OString` to get the encoded value.

These will be the values you hard code into the below **Batch Script** rather than using the sensitive values themselves in a plain text format.

```
$SensitiveString = "ARealDumbPassword" ## -- Put sensitive string value to encode here
$OString         = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($SensitiveString))
$ConvertedString = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($OString))
$OString ## -- Get encoded string value
```

[image]

You can use the existing batch script with a few adjustments so the encoded values can be passed in or set in the batch script logic and have the other logic within the PowerShell script to decode those values for use. Once done, the PowerShell script and the batch script will be deleted.

### Batch Script

```
@ECHO OFF

:: -- Set senvitive values and file attachment path
SET "GmailAccount=RwBtAGEAaQBsAEEAYwBjAG8AdQBuAHQAVQBzAGUAcgBuAGEAbQBlAF8AXwBCAGkAdABjAGgA"
SET "GmailPassword=QQBSAGUAYQBsAEQAdQBtAGIAQQBzAHMAUABhAHMAcwB3AG8AcgBkAA=="
SET "Attachment=<FullAttachmentPath>"

:: -- Set other email values
SET "EmailTo=Bob@BobMail.com"
SET "EmailSubject=This is the subject of the email"
SET "EmailBody=This is the body of the email"

CALL :PowerShell
CD /D "%PowerShellDir%"
Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PSScript%' '%GmailAccount%' '%GmailPassword%' '%Attachment%'"
IF EXIST "%PSScript%" DEL /Q /F "%PSScript%"
IF EXIST "%~FN0" DEL /Q /F "%~FN0"
IF EXIST "%PSScript%" DEL /Q /F "%PSScript%"
EXIT

:PowerShell
SET PowerShellDir=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
SET PSScript=%temp%\~tmpSendeMail.ps1
IF EXIST "%PSScript%" DEL /Q /F "%PSScript%"

ECHO $Username      = $args[0]                                                                                     >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $Username      = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($Username))     >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $EmailPassword = $args[1]                                                                                     >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $EmailPassword = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($EmailPassword))>> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $Attachment    = $args[2]                                                                                     >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $Attachment    = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($Attachment))   >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO                                          >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $Username    = $Username                 >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $EmailTo     = "%EmailTo%"               >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $EmailFrom   = "noreply@Whatever.notify" >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $Subject     = "%EmailSubject%"          >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $Body        = "%EmailBody%"             >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $SMTPServer  = "smtp.gmail.com"          >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body) >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $Attachment  = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($Attachment)                            >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $SMTPMessage.Attachments.Add($Attachment)                                                    >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $SMTPClient  = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)                              >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true                                                                >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $EmailPassword) >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)                                                               >> "%PSScript%"
GOTO :EOF
```

### Supporting Resources

- [Simple Obfuscation with PowerShell using Base64 Encoding](https://mikefrobbins.com/2017/06/15/simple-obfuscation-with-powershell-using-base64-encoding/)
- [Convert.ToBase64String Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string?view=netframework-4.7.2)
- [Encoding Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=netframework-4.7.2)
- [UnicodeEncoding.GetString(Byte[], Int32, Int32) Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.unicodeencoding.getstring?view=netframework-4.7.2)
- [System.Convert Methods](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/system-convert-methods)
- [Convert.FromBase64String(String) Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.frombase64string?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Proposed solution works well except that I get an error message related to @ECHO OFF : 

Commande : Le terme «Commande» n'est pas reconnu comme nom d'applet de commande, fonction, fichier de script ou programme exécutable. 
Au caractère C:\Users\Claude\AppData\Local\Temp\~tmpSendeMail.ps1:6 : 1
+ Commande ECHO dÃ©sactivÃ©e.
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Commande:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Translated : COMMANDE is not recognized as an applet, script or executable..
How can I get rid of this ?

Comment: @calade Try either **1.**  making it just `ECHO OFF` removing the `@` from it altogether, or **2.**  remove and do not use that entire line at all. It is really just an optional command in batch to not show output on the terminal window when batch is run, so it is unnecessary and purely an optional thing. I suspect it has to do with non-English language on your system since I wrote it on English set computer locale wise.

Comment: Thanks for your advices ! Same with ECHO OFF, curiously removing entire line breaks the program and I get : At character C:\Users\Claude\AppData\Local\Temp\~tmpSendeMail.ps1:6 : 20... terminator ' is missing in chain.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString, at line : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0>Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass ... ? Except warning message, program is working as described, congratulations ! It's just for my understanding,

Comment: @calade I wonder if it's the tilde and making this line `SET PSScript=%temp%\~tmpSendeMail.ps1` as `SET PSScript=%temp%\tmpSendeMail.ps1` would help.

Comment: Hell Vomit IT, that didn't help but I got it ! I had the idea to open tmpSendeMail.ps1 in PS ISE and at line 6, I read the infamous "Commande ECHO d‚sactiv‚e." which is fed there, why ? What is the use of this line, I don't know ? Anyhow, if I remove "ECHO                                          >> "%PSScript%"", no more warning message... Perhaps you can find an explanation... Also I forgot to ask why is there "IF EXIST "%PSScript%" DEL /Q /F "%PSScript%"" repeated two times before EXIT ? Thanks for your help and piece of software.

Comment: Hello, how can I change body message encoding to send a text with accentuated characters (UTF8 ?) please, I don't have much Powershell knowledge. Also, how to handle possible transmission errors ?